# Qlikview javascript

Tags: custom-controls, qlikview

Ho w do Insert JavaScript custom controls in QlikView .

Say I have a chart like a bar graph and I would embed this chart on my web application.

So now when I click on a Particular item in a Bar chart , my Page should go to a different webpage.

Answer (score 3):

To insert custom javascript you will need to build your own extension object: 
http://www.qlikblog.at/2848/qlikview-extension-tutorial-basic-concept/

If you are looking to embed objects to some website you can have a look at QV Workbench: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview-developer/12.0/Subsystems/QlikViewWorkBench/Content/workbench-start.htm

You can always create some kind of qlikview button with an action to open a new url.